# Leaving code on AMI to compile (Amazon EC2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rstudio-server

I ran a script on an `AMI` dedicated to `RStudio` which runs on top Ubuntu.

I closed the tab on the browser with the public DNS but when I open a new tab and open the public DNS again the script seem to be interrupted by something (as if `RStudio` relaunched).

Is there a way for me to close the browser tab (and my PC) safely to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What kind of server is it? (Ubuntu, Windows...)

Comment: Are you running some R code ? or it's the build it R studio UI? if yes, what kind of operation are doing on the UI?

Comment: I am running my own R code on RStudio